# Add-Member with Array value

Tags: powershell

Due to issues that I have with powershell classes (not having accessors and mutators aka getter and setters), I have been using Custom Objects created using add-member I am having an issue with figuring out the right way to reference array values in the SecondValue scriptblock.

For simple items the following code works fine

```
$Object = New-Object PSObject
Add-Member -InputObject $Object -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Array" -Value @() -Force
$Object.Array += 1
$Object.Array
$Object.Array[0] = 2
```

But because I want addition options (parameter validation, settings additional related properties) when setting the value I've been using the following format

```
$Object2 = New-Object PSObject
Add-Member -InputObject $Object2 -MemberType ScriptProperty -Name "Array" -Value {@($this.ArrayData)} -SecondValue{
    param($NewValue)
    $this.ArrayData = $NewValue}
Add-Member -InputObject $Object2 -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "ArrayData" -Value @() -Force
```

This does not work as expected because I don't know how to include the index in the SecondValue declaration. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to parameterize script properties. We can verify this by reading the PowerShell source. Internally, script properties' bookkeeping is stored in [`PSScriptProperty`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.psscriptproperty?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=powershellsdk-1.1.0) objects. When such properties' values are requested or altered, the private function `InvokeGetter` or `InvokeSetter`, respectively, are called. [`InvokeSetter`](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/fb286e6cf8480fe6df8a5a96311d6758e5c2b9f3/src/System.Management.Automation/engine/MshMemberInfo.cs#L1834) runs the setter script block with the new value as the only argument (as seen in the last line of this excerpt):

```
SetterScript.DoInvokeReturnAsIs(
    useLocalScope: true,
    errorHandlingBehavior: ScriptBlock.ErrorHandlingBehavior.WriteToExternalErrorPipe,
    dollarUnder: AutomationNull.Value,
    input: AutomationNull.Value,
    scriptThis: scriptThis,
    args: new object[] { value });
```

[`InvokeGetter`](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/fb286e6cf8480fe6df8a5a96311d6758e5c2b9f3/src/System.Management.Automation/engine/MshMemberInfo.cs#L1866) runs the getter script block with no arguments at all:

```
return GetterScript.DoInvokeReturnAsIs(
    useLocalScope: true,
    errorHandlingBehavior: ScriptBlock.ErrorHandlingBehavior.SwallowErrors,
    dollarUnder: AutomationNull.Value,
    input: AutomationNull.Value,
    scriptThis: scriptThis,
    args: Utils.EmptyArray<object>());
```

Therefore, we can't pass any extra information to the getter or setter. (`scriptThis` only refers to `$this`, the object we're setting the property on.)

There is a workaround: the [`Add-Type`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/add-type?view=powershell-5.1) cmdlet with the `-TypeDefinition` parameter. You can embed some C# (or VB.NET, if you prefer) code that defines an [indexable type](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/indexers/using-indexers):

```
Add-Type -TypeDefinition @"
using System;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
public class SomeClass {
    private int[] myArray;
    public SomeClass(int Capacity) {
        myArray = new int[Capacity];
    }
    [IndexerName("ArrayData")] public int this[int index] {
        get {
            Console.WriteLine("Somebody asked for the element at index " + index.ToString() + "!");
            return myArray[index];
        }
        set {
            if (value < 0) throw new InvalidOperationException("Negative numbers not allowed");
            if (index == 0) throw new InvalidOperationException("The first element cannot be changed");
            myArray[index] = value;
        }
    }
}
"@
```

You can then do something like this:

```
$obj = [SomeClass]::new(5)
$obj[3] = 255
Write-Host $obj[3] # Prints the "somebody accessed" notice, then 255
```

Or you can take advantage of the indexer name and do this:

```
$obj.ArrayData(3) = 255 # Note the parentheses, not brackets
Write-Host $obj.ArrayData(3) # Prints the notice, then 255
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was afraid that this was the case, but you provided more than enough supporting evidence to dispell any lingering doubt.